# Remove white space on each element - trim

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the white space of each items `.amount`

I'm using `trim` with `each` on the `.amount` class but it doesn't seems to work:

```
jQuery('.amount').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).text().trim();
})
```

I'm still getting the white space:

```
<span class="amount">€  159</span>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, `trim` only trims prepended or appended whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not trying to trim, but to replace the spaces in the content. `trim()` will remove only leading and trailing spaces, not the spaces within the content

```js
jQuery('button').click(function() {
  jQuery('.amount').text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/\s+/, '');
  })
})
```

```css
.amount {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="amount">€  159</span>
<button>Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your code wont remove spaces in between text:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.amount').text(function() {
    return this.innerHTML.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="amount">€  159</span>
<span class="amount">€      2.06</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`\s` is the regex for "whitespace", and `g` is the "global" flag, meaning match ALL `\s` (whitespaces).

each contiguous string of space characters is being replaced with the empty string because of the `+`.

```
<span class="amount">€  159</span>

    var str = '€  159';

    $(".amount").html( str.replace(/\s+/g, '') );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52LLzb6r/

Answer (score 0):

This replaces the text inside your spans with class 'amount'

```
$('.amount').each(function(){
    var $elem = $(this);
    $elem.html($elem.text().replace(/\s+/, ''));
})
```